# Why does Jokowi intend to release Abu Bakr Baasyir from prison?

Tags: indonesia

Jokowi [intends on releasing Abu Bakr Baasyir](https://en.tempo.co/read/1166408/why-president-jokowi-orders-release-of-abu-bakar-baasyir), a suspected terrorist charged with involvement in the 2002 Bali bombings and the 2003 Marriot Hotel bomb attack:

> “Today I want to announce President Jokowi’s intent on releasing Abu Bakar Ba'asyir from prison,” said Yusril Ihza during a Friday prayer he led at the Gunung Sindur Penitentiary, where Baasyir is currently being held.
>
> According to Yusril, President Jokowi decided to release Ba'asyir on the grounds of compassion and humanity regarding the 81-year-old prisoner's declining health.

The article quotes that it's for "compassion". That's the political front of the answer. I mean, there are plenty of other criminals that also have done a long time in jail. Why did Jokowi do that? What incentive does Jokowi have to free a terrorist leader like Abu Bakr Baasyir? Are there enough voters that sympathize and want Abu Bakr Baasyir free?

Comment: It might be interesting to note that at some point Abu Bakr Baasyir's sentence was reduced to 9 years (and then reinstated to 15 years), which means that he would be released right about now. This might not explain why Jokowi decided to release him, but it might explain the timing.

Comment: There could be a deal due to Ahok release that will happen soon

Comment: Rolled back your last edit. There's no need to provide that much background information. People attempting to answer the question should already be fully aware of who Abu Bakr Baasyir is. If not, they shouldn't be attempting to answer the question in the first place.

Comment: I think it's not just for those who answer but for every body so they can quickly know what's the issue is all about. Someone come to this site, look at this question, and wonder who the hell is Abu Bakr. I give quick quotation. I would roll back to my own edit. Seriously.

Comment: This isn't a news site, or a blog. If people are interested in knowing more about the people and the topics discussed in questions, they can do their own research. Please keep your posts concise and to the point.

Comment: Is this a normal policy of politic stackexchange? If so, I will abide. Can anyone confirm? It's not a news site, but at least it gives people a quick overview. Usually people complain I don't put enough info. Do others agree with Yannis? Don't get me wrong. Abu Bakr Basyir is not famous.

Comment: Usually people complain for the opposite reason. So that's why I want to know

Comment: People complain because you usually don't put enough information _necessary to understand what exactly you are asking_. That is not the case here. Your question is clear enough. The background information you added didn't make it any clearer, and it might even distract from the actual question. This isn't a matter of policy, it is a matter of efficient discourse. Don't waffle.

Comment: Someone put that he is a suspect of terror Bomb. That's good enough.

Comment: I hope that someone who’s been in jail that long has been convicted of something, not merely charged. (BTW, as an Aussie I’m surprised this isn’t front page news in Australia)

Comment: Inconsistent nouns: *"a suspected terrorist"* is not necessarily the same thing as *"a terrorist leader"*.

Comment: He is a terrorist leader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was yusril and yusril only. He released press conference without telling Joko Widodo. Essentially, backstabbing him. But as he released conference, and claimed that he got permission from jokowi, the palace has issued hasty press conference that the release was being reviewed. 
Yusril has long been known as radical supporter. And he is backstabbing jokowi has been a talk in jokowi alliance. The habit of claiming something under other people's name is also a habit from radicals trying to oust jokowi. But this time, it seems one of them getting inside and try to use his position to make claim.

Jokowi himself has never put a talk to that, and it seems that yusril want to force Joko Widodo's hand by claiming that jokowi wanted to release the terrorist. Luckily, it didn't play out as yusril planned.

You should see more interesting news as radicals trying to topple jokowi, as they are bound to never fight Moslem leader, but got a very resistant Moslem at that. That news like yusril was one of hundreds that we experienced on daily basis, and jokowi have to play gracefully to stop them. But lately, jokowi seems fed up, and he is on offense now. It's more like a real life highly complicated chess to fool people and to educate people, plus to blind people for their group. Already, they posted a blacklisted news media that they claimed to broadcast lies to block their followers from real world and only feed on information those group provides. These information are usually only posted in their facebook groups. I found a lot of information like this Baasyir in their pages, and tried to take them down.

Bad news is, Facebook makes it easy for them, and harder for us to counter their lies. There are fake news report on Facebook, and they produce it very single day, in massive amount, to Facebook groups. And Facebook always note them as conform to community standard. When I post links of what really happened, Facebook blocked me by saying that I abuse the feature. So, that they can keep pushing people to rebel against their government by using news like this in their facebook group. I already seen the urge to rebel against Indonesia government because Jokowi had lied to his people, just from this news. So, actually, if you ask me, it is for Yusril's incentive. Everyone in their group thinks that ABB didn't bomb or planned the bombing, and with this cancellation news in their page, you can imagine what they think. That is what this release news for.

Comment: Can you provide some references for this answer? Also, how it the last paragraph relevant?

Comment: I am Indonesian. All this time it's Yusril and Yusril again that keep saying Jokowi will free ABB. Then Jokowi says no. Jokowi says he may do that but the laws say no.

Comment: @user4951 Can you provide some sources for that? Maybe a verbatim quote and when and where it was said? When Yusril  says it "all the time" it should be easy to find an example of it. And when Jokowi really said no, then it should also be possible to find a quote. Also, you might want to remove the last paragraph. You might have good reasons to criticize Facebook's moderation practices, but this question isn't the place to do that. Answers should answer the question that was asked, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: @Alexei Not directly. But this kind of news, is exactly what they intended to spread through facebook. Then it would be said, as in facebook, that Jokowi had lied, and therefore needs to be taken down. You won't find that in news, only in facebook, in their "dedicated" news group, protected from outside reach.

Comment: @Philipp Yes. But you won't find that in english release. Strange on how media picks what would cause bigger wrecks?  Try to translate this. 
https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1167782/abu-bakar-baasyir-batal-dibebaskan-begini-penjelasan-moeldoko

Comment: @Philipp as for facebook, this kind of news is intended to make into their facebook group, to fuel their will to rebel against government since the government had lied to its citizen. They spread all kind of these work in their facebook and push people to war. So now you know why it is hard to fight terrorism. They smartly produce a news like this baasyir, and twist them to spread in facebook groups. So, actually, instead of jokowi's, its terrorist's incentive, or in this question, Yusril's incentive. to produce some twisted news in facebook.

Comment: To be honest, Jokowi does take a while before outright rejecting the news.